# How to augment udpipe models with custom dictionary?

Tags: r, nlp, udpipe

Is there a way to add a dictionary of custom user defined words to the `udpipe models`?

For example, below using the default `english` model, some of the words should have been
identified as the keywords, such as `R`, `Python`, `SQL`, `javascript`, `Excel`, `noSQL`.

I would like to augment the default `english` model with my own custom words, so that the `textrank_keywords` function will be able to better identify relevant keywords.

```
library(udpipe)
library(dplyr)
tagger <- udpipe_download_model("english")
tagger <- udpipe_load_model(tagger$file_model)

# read data
rawdata <- c("Automating and R/Python package development.","You have a sound knowledge of another data analysis language (R,Python, SQL, javascript) and you don't care in which relational database, Excel, bigdata or noSQL store your data is located.")

# annotate
rawdata_annotate <- udpipe_annotate(tagger, rawdata) %>% as_tibble()

keyw <- textrank_keywords(rawdata_annotate$lemma,
                          relevant = rawdata_annotate$upos %in% c("PROPN","NOUN", "VERB", "ADJ"))

have <- keyw$terms
[1] "package"    "analysis"   "sound"      "relational"

rawdata_annotate %>% dplyr::filter(token %in% c('R', 'Python', 'SQL', 'javascript', 'Excel', 'noSQL')) %>% dplyr::select(token, lemma, upos)

  token      lemma      upos 
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 R          R          PROPN
2 Python     python     NOUN 
3 R          r          NOUN 
4 Python     python     NOUN 
5 SQL        sql        NOUN 
6 javascript javascript NOUN 
7 Excel      Excel      PROPN
8 noSQL      nosql      AUX
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. Basically I would need to create a custom
`CONLL-U` file for the custom annotation. And then train the model.

```
https://bnosac.github.io/udpipe/docs/doc3.html
```